Invalidate / Pull back MS word document sent out via email as an attachment
I sent out somebody's resume as an attachment to the wrong recipient via an email. Is there a way to invalidate (or pull back) this attachment remotely? The original document saved in my PC is still in the original location in my PC.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Unless the email service used offers the ability to unsend, no. AFAIK, the only way to do so without the aforementioned would be using a OneDrive or similar link to the document, which would allow removing the sharing setting for the document

There is not; Even if your using a service that does support replacing an email with another email the recipient email server must also support it and even if their service does the recipient can just decline the request.

There are certain limited circumstances where you can recall an email, and they mostly boil down to: Are you in a business environment on the same email server as the person you mistakenly sent this email to.
Another edge case would be if you work in an OneDrive/OneDrive for Business/Google Drive/or other "cloud" storage environment, AND you sent the attachment by sharing it via this "cloud" storage system, you would have created a share with the recipient and you can end that share by following the steps appropriate for that system, but if the recipient already downloaded the file you'd be out of luck.
If the wrong recipient has a different email domain (your email ends in @acme.com and their email ends in @widgets.com) you're out of luck. If either of your email addresses are personal, free, and/or on a generic email domain such as gmail, or hotmail, or live, or proton, or yahoo, or anything else like that, you're out of luck.
Sending an attachment via email creates a copy of that file, and the moment that email leaves your email server, it is entirely out of your hands and out of your control.
